# Do not include results of customers who havent made a recent order?

Tags: sql, oracle

Determine how many orders have been placed by each customer. Do not include in the results any customer who hasn’t recently placed an order.

```
order#  customer# orderdate
============================
1000    1005    31-MAR-09 
1001    1010    31-MAR-09
1002    1011    31-MAR-09
1003    1001    01-APR-09
1004    1020    01-APR-09
1005    1018    01-APR-09
1006    1003    01-APR-09
1007    1007    02-APR-09
1008    1004    02-APR-09
1009    1005    03-APR-09
1010    1019    03-APR-09
1011    1010    03-APR-09
1012    1017    03-APR-09
1013    1014    03-APR-09
1014    1007    04-APR-09
1015    1020    04-APR-09
1016    1003    04-APR-09
1017    1015    04-APR-09
1018    1001    05-APR-09
1019    1018    05-APR-09
1020    1008    05-APR-09
```

Below is my SQL query in Oracle

```
select count(orderdate)    
from books     
group by customer#
```

As for the results, I get the total of
books each customer ordered. However it also states that I need 
to include only the most recent orders.

Comment: You need to define **recently**, that means the last week? The last month? Yesterday? The last quarter?

Comment: You can select code then  hit ctrl + K to format code as code

Comment: Hello, it's for a course ? Maybe you should try it by yourself.

Comment: Use `having` clause, for instance `having max(orderdate) >= date '2009-04-04'` shows only results for customers, who ordered something *recently*.

Comment: Google SQL Where clause and you can find what your looking for. Like @nacho said you need to define what "Most recent" means and use that as part of your clause.

Answer (score 1):

When aggregating, you would normally include the `group by` keys.

Your question is about filtering.  If you want to count *all* orders, but only for customers who have made a recent order, then the filtering is *after* the aggregation.  Use a `having` clause:

```
select customer#, count(*)    
from books     
group by customer#
having max(orderdate) >= date '2009-04-01';  -- or whatever the cutoff is for "recent"
```

If you only want to count *recent* orders, then you want the filtering *before* aggregation.  So you using a `where` clause:

```
select customer#, count(*)    
from books
where orderdate >= date '2009-04-01'
group by customer#;
```

The counts will be different in each case.  Also notice the use of the `date` keyword so you can express a date constant as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Yeah I think this is what I am looking for. The question is vague. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a where(date>02-APR-09) so you get only the orders with a date larger than the specified one.